# How to include two NJK templates one inside the other?

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

**I have three templates in this case:**

**1)** Home Page

**2)** Modal button

**3)** Filter Form

The **Filtering Form** is included within **(2)** and the **Modal Butto**n is included within **(1)**!

However I am getting a hierarchy problem from the **NJK folders**, in case I remove **(3)** from within **(2)** it to the error .. But the paths are correct and I realized that it ends up creating a location from my include main that is the **(2)** within **(1)** ...

**PATHS**

**1)** `app\backend\src\views\pages\home.njk`

**2)** `app\backend\src\views\templates\buttons\modals\filter.njk`

**3)** `app\backend\src\views\templates\forms\filters\global.njk`

**THE INCLUSION OF THE MODAL BUTTON IN THE HOME PAGE:**

`{% include '../templates/buttons/modals/filter.njk' %}` **OK**

**THE INCLUSION OF THE FILTER FORM IN THE MODAL BUTTON:**

`{% include '../templates/forms/filters/global.njk' %}` **ERROR**

**ERROR:**

```
Template render error: (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\app\backend\src\views\pages\home.njk)
  Template render error: (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\app\backend\src\views\templates\buttons\modals\filter.njk)
  Error: template not found: C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\app\backend\src\views\templates\buttons\templates\forms\filters\global.njk
    at Object._prettifyError (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:36:11)
    at C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:547:19
    at eval (eval at _compile (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:20:11)
    at C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:555:11
    at eval (eval at _compile (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:14:11)
    at createTemplate (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:279:11)
    at next (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:282:7)
    at handle (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:313:11)
    at C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:323:9
    at next (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:280:7)
    at Object.asyncIter (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:286:3)
    at Environment.getTemplate (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:305:9)
    at eval (eval at _compile (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:13:5)
    at fn (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\a-sync-waterfall\index.js:26:24)
    at C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\a-sync-waterfall\index.js:66:22
    at executeSync (C:\Users\THIAGOSAAD\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\node_modules\a-sync-waterfall\index.js:8:15)
```

Comment: Try to setup `nunjucks`-path on init: `nunjucks.configure(['../views/templates','../views/pages'], [opts]);` and use only local path `{% include "forms/filters/global.njk" %}`.

Comment: How funny, now it was! Why does it get lost in the paths? Enter your answer that I give you point.

Comment: I think that absolute path applyed to current template path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to setup nunjucks-path on init: `nunjucks.configure(['../views/templates','../views/pages'], [opts]);` and use only local path `{% include "forms/filters/global.njk" %}`.